# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Object.<anonymous> (userhistory.js:23)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm having an issue with this snippet of code I'm working on. I've been using this chat feature that I found at the link below. When I use it as is integrated into my application it works perfectly fine, although I've had trouble modifying that. However to create a user history feature for my site I took to recreating this feature using the same basic system but with different variables. However I can't seem to get past why I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userhistory.js:21)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
```

It's very strange because the original and my version are almost identical with some differences, however mine gives me this syntax error. I've read some similar posts here but none have really answered my question other than to say do it a different way. But since this same syntax works already with slightly different variables, I'm inclined to find out why mine won't work. Any help would be appreciated. I posted the code from the working version below, and I've posted the simple html doc I'm using to test. And I've gone over mine character by character to make sure I didn't miss something, I doubled down on that right before I clicked post here just to prevent the ultimate noob fail. Thanks in advance guys.

https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html

userhistory.js

```
var userID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSend').click(function(){
        updateHistory();
        $('#input').val("");
    });
    startHistory();
});

function startHistory(){
    setInterval(function(){ getHistory(); }, 2000);
}

function getHistory(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/refreshhistory.php?userID="+userID
    }).done(function( data )
    {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data); <-- This is where the debugger shows an error
        var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.results[i];
            html += '<div id="tb-testimonial" class="testimonial testimonial-primary-filled">'+'<div class="testimonial-section">(' + result.actionDate+ ') <b>' + result.userID +'</b>: '+result.action+ '</div>'+'</div>'+'<div class="input-group">'+'<hr/>'+'</div>';
            userID = result.userID;
        }
        $('#view_history').append(html);
    });
}

function updateHistory(){
    var input = $('#input').val();
    if(input != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/newhistory.php?action="+encodeURIComponent( input )
        });
    }
}
```

messages.js

```
var lastTimeID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSend').click(function(){
        sendChatText();
        $('#chatInput').val("");
    });
    startChat();
});

function startChat(){
    setInterval(function(){ getChatText(); }, 2000);
}

function getChatText(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID="+lastTimeID
    }).done(function( data )
    {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.results[i];
            html += '<div id="tb-testimonial" class="testimonial testimonial-primary-filled">'+'<div class="testimonial-section">(' + result.chattime+ ') <b>' + result.usrname +'</b>: '+result.chattext+ '</div>'+'</div>'+'<div class="input-group">'+'<hr/>'+'</div>';
            lastTimeID = result.id;
        }
        $('#view_ajax').append(html);
    });
}

function sendChatText(){
    var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
    if(chatInput != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
        });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

                <div class="col-sm-6" id="view_history">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="btn btn-secondary" id="ajaxForm">
                        <input type="text" class="input-large search-query" id="input" /><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>             
<script type="text/javascript" src="userhistory.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

refreshhistory.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("/dbconnect.php");
require_once("/userhistoryclass.php");
$userID = intval($_GET['userID'] );
$jsonData = userHistoryClass::getuserHistory($userID);
print $jsonData;
?>
```

As requested I went directly to the refreshhistory.php?userID=my_ID and got the results as

```
{"results":[{"accountID":"ba7c7ed76e0270fdf1a0a616d3c02849","action":"dasdfadsfasdfasdf","actionDate":"02:34:22"},{"accountID":"ba7c7ed76e0270fdf1a0a616d3c02849","action":"DASDFDFDFD","actionDate":"03:15:02"}]}
```

So that is working, however the parsing issue still remains. Just wanted to update this.

So my problem was that I wasn't calling the right location within the JS file, I assumed that js worked like PHP and would recognize the folder it was located in so I didn't put an extra reference to the specific folder. Noob mistake. Thank you James and Jeff for your help in figuring out I have a long way to go :)

Comment: It's because refreshhistory.php isn't returning valid JSON (maybe an error message in HTML format).  I suggest you visit the exact url (with the userID parameter) in your browser and see what you get.

Comment: have a look at the network tab (of dev-tools in your browser) to see what get returned from server. This looks like an error-message

Comment: @James I added the refreshhistory.php actually now that you mention it the intval function might be the problem. The userID is a string technically that isn't just integers. Would you be able to recommend another format?

Comment: @Jeff, the network log complete looks like this, keeps spamming this. 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userhistory.js:21)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
(anonymous) @ userhistory.js:21
i @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2
z @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
test.html:2

Comment: I meant the network tab, not the console! You show the js-errors, that are a response to the php errors you'll see in network tab.

Comment: Yep check the network tab of browser developer tools or visit your `refreshhistory.php?userID=your_user_id` in a browser and see if you get a JSON looking page or a big nasty error for you to fix (yes intval will fail if you pass it a non-numeric string)

Comment: ok so I did what you asked @James, first I changed intval to strval and that allowed me to pull data when I went directly to the url with the userID like you suggested. It's getting the sample data I put into the db directly. But since I'm still getting the error that I mentioned above it isn't parsing that data. I'm looking through the network log and its keeps refreshing refreshhistory.php?userID=my_ID like it's supposed to. I don't see where else I should look within that tab. I'm using Chrome if that helps.

Comment: It's very strange though, the page is calling dashboard.php and it says initiator is refreshhistory.php for some reason. Every time that file runs it makes a call to the dashboard which I don't know why it would since I have no obvious requests to that page.

Comment: You want to check the server response from the refreshhistory request, looking for anything that's not JSON

Comment: So I noticed it was saying 303 bad, and it was calling the refreshhistory from the main folder, so I moved it from the controller folder it was in, that changed it to 200 OK, I looked at the response and it was saying it didn't like the location for the db connection and the userhistoryclass, I changed those and now it's working. And then I realized that my userhistory.js file calls a specific location. I added the controller folder and boom it works. So it after all was a noob mistake. Thank you for the debugging crash course guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have already gotten the same problem:

I did that:

```
 $.get('ping', function(response) {
                   console.log(typeof response);
                  var res = JSON.parse(response);
                  if (res.showButton) {
                  var temps = res.time; // 'matin' or 'soir'
```

... the rest of the code.

When I run it I got:

```
VM13008:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (new:21)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

the same error as you.

I clicked here **VM13040:1**  I saw that  : **[object Object]**.

I think that the problem might be the problem of **conversion**(I'm not sure).

To solve this problem just do like this :

Ommit:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

and work directly with `response`;`data` in your case.

In my case the code will look like this:

```
function pingServer() {
                console.log('to ping');
              $.get('ping', function(response) {
               console.log(typeof response);
              if (response.showButton) {
              var temps = response.time; // 'matin' or 'soir'
```

... the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when data passed to JSON parse function is not a valid json.
Use regex to validate if data is json string and then use parse function accordingly.You can use below code to validate the same.

```
if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {

  //add json parse function here

}else{

  //if not json string then handle it here

}
```